# Realm db change directory - React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm, react-native

I have a problem finding the **.realm file** directory on **Android 5.1**. On a phone with a higher Android, I can easily find the file in **Android Studio**. I need some way to change the **.realm** file directory or make a copy to the download folder for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening the realm with `Realm.open`, you can override the path where the realm file should be stored: [docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#opening-realms).

```
Realm.open({
  schema: [...],
  path: "path/to/my.realm",
})
  .then(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !, I had not paying much attention to this step when I read the documentation